# Set Telltale's Game of Throne to display prompts for PS3 controller on PC?

Tags: game-of-thrones

I have Telltale's Game of Throne game on Steam with a PS3 controller plugged in. But for some reason the button prompts are for a 360 controller.

How can I change it to PS3 prompts? I do not know what buttons it prompts for and I am continually dying in QTEs.

In Final Fantasy XIV on PC we're able to set PS3 button prompts.

Comment: PlayStation 3 controllers aren't officially supported on Windows, you need to use third party drivers to make them work, so it's possible that Telltale never designed the game to work with one on Windows.

Comment: When you use an XInput device, games tend to assume it's an Xbox 360 controller.

Comment: I play FFXIV daily on PC and I'm able to do it there, so I guess I'm used to it.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I change it to PS3 prompts?

You can't.

The overwhelming majority of games are designed for XBOX controller prompts.

Why, you ask? Simple, a majority of people us an XBOX controller over a PS3 controller because there are officially supported windows drivers and the Games for Windows certification program requires XBOX controller support.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee417691(v=vs.85).aspx#tr_1_4

> **Requirement**
>   Games that support gamepad controllers must support the
>   Xbox 360 Controller for Windows using the XInput API. If DirectInput
>   peripherals are also supported, then DirectInput can also be used.
>   However, XInput must be the default API if an Xbox 360 compatible
>   device is used. ***All references to common controller triggers and
>   buttons must use the Xbox 360 names.*** See the Xbox 360 Common
>   Controller for Windows Terminology list for details. Controller
>   vibration must be turned off when the game is in a paused or suspended
>   state. Mouse/keyboard control cannot be fully disabled at any time. At
>   a minimum, an option to return to game menus must be available.
>
> **Rationale**
>   This requirement gives gamers freedom of choice to use
>   either the Xbox 360 controller or the keyboard and mouse, depending on
>   which input method is more natural and intuitive interface.
>
> **Additional**
>   Information This requirement does not apply to games that use only the
>   mouse and/or the keyboard. We recommend that menu navigation be
>   implemented to use the widely accepted standard controller buttons: A
>   - Accept B - Cancel Start - Accept or pause Back - Cancel, back one screen or up a menu level

The Final Fantasy games are one of the few titles that will have in game PS3 controller prompts as Final Fantasy was/is primarily a PS title.